# Unique Linear Map- Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, linear-transformations

Let $E = {e_1, . . . , e_n}$ be a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$
, and let $v_1, . . . , v_n$ be arbitrary vectors in
$\mathbb{R}^m$.

Prove that there is a unique linear map $T : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ such that $T(e_i) = v_i$ for all $i = 1, . . . , n$

This feels like such a trivial question just what's the point of it?
I didnt really know what to do but after stumbling around for a few mins not knowing what exacly I was trying to show-

You can work backwords to $T(\lambda_1e_1+\lambda_2e_2+...+\lambda_ne_n)=\lambda_1v_1+\lambda_2v_2+...+\lambda_nv_n$.
Which apparently is enough to show that you have found a linear map- why? All I did was play with properties of linear transformations.

**Main Question:**

I reckon the key reason of this is that $E = {e_1, . . . , e_n}$ is a basis and you can represent every vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ as $\lambda_1e_1+\lambda_2e_2+...+\lambda_ne_n$ for arbitrary $\lambda_i$.

$\lambda_1v_1+\lambda_2v_2+...+\lambda_nv_n$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^m$ since each $v_i$ is in $\mathbb{R}^m$

So you have a map which is linear and takes every vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ to one in $\mathbb{R}^m$ .

Is this the reason? Or am I misunderstanding the crux of why $T(\lambda_1e_1+\lambda_2e_2+...+\lambda_ne_n)=\lambda_1v_1+\lambda_2v_2+...+\lambda_nv_n$ constitutes a proof that I have found a linear map $T : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$.

**Second Question:**

I now wish to show that this linear map is **unique**
Assume there exists another linear map $S$.If it must satisfy the properties stated in beginninig then there is no choice but for $S(\lambda_1e_1+\lambda_2e_2+...+\lambda_ne_n)=\lambda_1v_1+\lambda_2v_2+...+\lambda_nv_n$ to hold.
Since $S(v)=T(v)$ for all $v$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ they are same linear transformation and so T is unique.

Is this fine also?

If not I would really appreciate feedback on it and better/correct solutions. Thanks

Comment: How are $n$ and $m$ related? Is $n<m$ or $n\geq m$ or what?

Comment: @CC0607 does it really matter? The question doesnt specify anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are exactly right. You have defined $T:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ as:
$$T(\lambda_1e_1+\cdots\lambda_ne_n) = \lambda_1 T(e_1)+\cdots+\lambda_n T(e_n) = \lambda_1v_1+\cdots+\lambda_nv_n,$$
which by definition makes it linear. You proof that $T$ is unique is correct also. What you haven't checked is if your mapping is well defined (although it'll probably hardly take you any time). That is, if $v=w$, then $T(v)=T(w)$.

The important idea to take away from this question is that **any** linear transformation between finite dimensional vector spaces is uniquely determined by where it sends the basis vectors.

Furthermore, if $V$ and $W$ are finite dimensional vector spaces, such that
$$\dim{V}=\dim{W}=n,$$
and 
$$B_V = \{v_1,...,v_n\}\quad\text{and}\quad B_W=\{w_1,...,w_n\}$$
are bases for $V$ and $W$ respectively, then defining $T(v_j) = w_j$ automatically makes $T$ an isomorphism.

Comment: How do I show it's well defined? Prove that if $v= $ $\lambda_1e_1+\lambda_2e_2+...+\lambda_ne_n$ and $w=v $Then it must also be written uniquely in the same way as $\lambda_1e_1+\lambda_2e_2+...+\lambda_ne_n$ since $E$ is a basis. Proof: Assume $w= $ $\mu_1e_1+\mu_2e_2+...+\mu_ne_n$ Then $(\lambda_1-\mu_1)e_1+(\lambda_2-\mu_2)e_2+...+(\lambda_n-\mu_2)e_n=0$. Since $E$ is a basis and $e_i$ are linearly indep. Then $\lambda_i=\mu_i$ QED. So clearly both $T(v)$ and $T(w) $ map to $\lambda_1v_1+\lambda_2v_2+...+\lambda_nv_n$

Comment: @Arcane1729 That is perfect. Nice job.

Answer (score 1):

I want to point that it is a *very general* fact:

Let $A$ be a commutative ring. For *any* free $A$-module $L$, with basis $(e_i)_{i\in I}$ ($I$ finite or not) and for any $A$-module $E$, then
\begin{align*}\mathcal L_A(L,E)&\longrightarrow E^I\\
f&\longmapsto \bigl(f(e_i)\bigr)_{i\in I}
\end{align*}
is an isomorphism of $R$-modules.

The proof is strictly the same as  for vector spaces over a field. The only difference is in the applications, since, unlike vector spaces, modules do not necessarily have a basis.

Comment: Ah I am but a humble first year undergrad haha- rings and modules is next year. I am sure it will be interesting to come back and understand

Comment: As I didn't know you grade level, I just wanted  to show the more general context, not to give a real proof. That said, once you know what is a module over a ring, it is the same proof as for vector module. Incidentally, the difference between modules and vector spaces, is that scalars are in a ring instead of being in a field, say $\mathbf R$ (i.e. you do not always have inverses for non-zero elements).