# Prove existence of linear map from a basis of V to arbitrary vectors in W

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

My question is regarding a theorem from linear algebra:

$V$ and $W$ are vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$. Given a basis $(v_1, \dotsc, v_n)$ of $V$ and arbitrary vectors $(w_1, \dotsc, w_n) \in W$, we can construct a unique linear map $T: V \rightarrow W$ such that $Tv_j = w_j$ for $j = 1, \dotsc, n$.

The sources I've looked at, including similar questions on stackexchange, do not elaborate on whether such a $T$ exists. **I understand the uniqueness of $T$, assuming it exists, but how can existence be proven?**

For example, since there are no restrictions on the dimensionality of $V$ and $W$, suppose we choose $v_1 = (1, 0)$, $v_2 = (0, 1)$ as a basis of $V = \mathbb{R}^2$ and $w_1 = (1, 2, \dotsc, 100)$ and $w_2 = (101, 102, \dotsc, 200)$ as the arbitrary vectors on $W = \mathbb{R}^{100}$. Although intuitively I can see how the independence of $v_1$ and $v_2$ allows for a mapping $T: V \rightarrow W$ to exist, I am having difficulty coming up with a proof.

Similar questions:

[1. Only proves uniqueness](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2291815/uniqueness-of-linear-maps-proof)

[2. Doesn't discuss existence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1409586/unique-linear-map-linear-algebra)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To construct a linear map $T: V \to W$, we have to show two things:

- Define the function $T$, i.e., for each $v \in V$, define $Tv \in W$
- Show that the function $T$ is linear

We start by defining $T$ as follows:

An arbitrary $v \in V$ can be expressed uniquely as $v = \sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_j v_j$ for scalars $\alpha_j$ (since the $v_j$ give a basis). We define $T(v)
 = \sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_j w_j$. Now we've given a unique output of the function $T$ for each $v \in V$, so the function $T$ is defined.

The only constraints placed on $T$ in the question were that $Tv_j = w_j$ for all $j$. Looking at our definition, we confirm that this is true.

We then have to make sure $T$ is linear, which amounts to checking two conditions:

- Given $v, v' \in V$, show that $T(v + v') = Tv + Tv'$
- Given a scalar $\beta$ and $v \in V$, show that $\beta Tv = T(\beta v)$

I'm going to let you work that part out on your own, but feel free to comment if you're stuck on this part.

Comment: Thank you, but the part I'm having trouble understanding is:

Given an arbitrary set of vectors $w_1, ..., w_n \in W$, how do we know that a mapping $Tv_j = w_j$ exists? You say that such a $T$ is given, but I'm not understanding how to prove the existence of such a $T$. Please see the last paragraph of my question for a numerical example in case I am not articulating this well.

Comment: @tmakino Recall the definition of a function. $T$ exists (as a function) as long as we can assign, for each input $v \in V$, some $w \in W$; and as long as we never assign two different $w \in W$ to the same $v \in V$. Are you having trouble understanding how the assignment is made, or how to ensure that we never assign two different $w \in W$ to the same $v \in V$?

Comment: @tmakino Also note that in my answer I don't say $T$ is given; I say we're given the value of $T$ at two points in $V$, and I explicitly define the value of $T$ at the rest of the points in $V$. I'll try to edit to make clearer.

Comment: @tmakino Edited my answer. Let me know if it's any clearer.

Comment: The part I don't understand is that given an arbitrary choice of vectors in $W$, say $w_1 = (1, 2, \dotsc, 100)$ and $w_2 = (1001, 1002, \dotsc, 1100)$, why we know that there is a $T$ that maps basis vectors in $V$ to those pre-selected vectors $w_1, w_2$.

Comment: @tmakino We can create such a $T$. For something to be a function, we need only assign an output to each input in the domain. So I know there exists a function $f$ from the set of primary colors {red, green, blue} to the set of months {January, February, ...} which maps green to May because I can create such a function by assigning $f$(red) = March, $f$(green) = May, $f$(blue) = October. We're doing the same thing here: assigning, in your example, $T(1,0) = (1, 2, \dots, 100)$ and $T(0,1) = (1001, 1002, \dots, 1100)$.

Comment: Thank you, that clears it up for me.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a basis every vector in your vector space has a unique representation as a linear combination of the basis vectors. If you know the image of the basis vectors you can define the image of an arbitrary vector using linearity of the transformation. Note that the unique representation of a vector as a linear combination of the basis vectors is the key for the linear transformation to be well defined.